# enquiry of Json with json p -probloms with geting output

Tags: json, api, jquery, getjson

hello i'm trying to retrive from http://www.numbeo.com//api/city_prices?api_key=lnu_se_713&query=vaxjo each "item_name" and "average_price" from each object/item inside price...
i'm not able to retrive nothing from the json , and i belive that somthing is missing in my call or worng

```
var url = "http://www.numbeo.com//api/city_prices?api_key=lnu_se_713&query=vaxjo";
    var src;
     $.getJSON(url+ "&format=json&jsoncallback=?" , function (data) {
        $.each(data[].prices.average_price, function (i, item) {
alert(object.prices.average_price);

        });
    });
```

evntually i whould like to presnet only 3 items 
("Meal Inexpensive Restaurant","Combo Meal at McDonalds","Domestic Beer") as tables heads and to append to them averge price as valeus.

please help me

Comment: why you use `data[]`? simply `data.prices`

Comment: but when im trying to retrive : data.prices.average_price it is not working , i try to alert it and get eror token is missing

Comment: what exactly `data[].` means?. If you want to get the array just use it's name `data.`

Answer (score -1):

```
$json_string ="https://www.numbeo.com/api/city_prices?api_key=enter  key=entes city";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
foreach($obj['prices'] as $results)
{
echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$results['item_name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$results['lowest_price'].'</td>
        <td>'.$results['highest_price'].'</td>
        <td>'.$results['average_price'].'</td>
        ';
        }
```